# Updating Wordpress test-database with new data from production database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We have an old blog running and since the remote server has some problems as well we decided to tear it all down. So I started a while ago to create a new blog on our locale testserver with a complete new theme-design. Therefore I dumped the database 2 months ago as fundation and went from there to create the blog. So in the meanwhile the production server (with the old theme) received a lot new data which needs to be integrated into our testblog server database. All databases we use are MySQL

So we are talking about three server:

1. OLD Production Server (With old Theme, which is currently running and has all the new information)
2. Test Server (Which we were using to design the new theme. Except to the others it is a local server)
3. NEW Production Server (This is were the new blog from the Test Server should move to with all the new data from the OLD Production Server)

Here is what I did (I made a Server Snapshot):

I dumped the old wordpress database without a few tables as you can see in the code.

OLD Production Server

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --ignore-table=wordpress.wp_options
--ignore-table=wordpress.wp_term_relationships --ignore-table=wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy --ignore-table=wordpress.wp_terms --ignore-table=wordpress.wp_wp_rp_tags vfl_blog > wordpress_tables_dump.sql
```

Test Server

```
mysql -uroot -p --one-database wordpress < wordpress_tables_dump.sql
```

These are the tables which I dumped after ignoring the other tables:

- wp_commentmeta
- wp_comments
- wp_links
- wp_postmeta
- wp_posts
- wp_usermeta
- wp_users

After I did that Wordpress asks me to confirm to rebuild the database. After the process is done all the settings from the new theme and plugins on our testserver are gone. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Have you looked at the database to see where the theme stores its' settings? Some use a custom post type for that, and those posts would get overwritten when you import the current data.

Comment: I tried to figure that out and I already contacted the developer. So far no one has answered yet. To prevent overriding these settings I tried just to dump only post, comments and user tables with it meta datas

Comment: I edited the tables which I actually dumped in the end

Comment: Another common thing: if you've made changes in your tables by simply replacing values (https://example.com => https://www.example.org for example), you might damage the serialized values if the lengths of the two strings differ. I hope the developers get back to you.

Comment: How can I work around that? Obviously there are wordpress settings beeing imported, because after database import wordpress wants to use the old theme design, which is not installed anymore. The new theme is installed though, but all settings are gone from the new theme

Comment: Have a look at your SQL-Dump, are you certain that the options-table isn't in there? I took a second look at your mysqldump, you're excluding wordpress.wp_options, but dumping the DB vfl_blog, that should probably be vfl_blog.wp_options etc.

Comment: Oh my gosh... Thank you a thousend times. Yes I actually confussed the db name... After I dumped it again the result is something completly else. It is still not how it supose to be, but at least the settings from the new theme are still in use. Thank you again

Comment: There is still one last problem. The pages I created (such as the new Impressum or Contacts ...) are beeing deleted through the table import. I will try to ignore table by table to figure out which table is causing this behaviour. Do you have an idea as well?

Comment: Glad the original thing worked out. As for the pages: those should be in wp_posts as well. Are they disappearing from the DB or just not accessible because of a permalink problem / rewrite rules / something else?